# Expand shell variable without globbing

Tags: bash, wildcards, test, variable-substitution

I want to check whether an input string refers to a file name - **not** a wildcard string like `*.txt`.

This doesn't work:

```
if [ -f "$1" ];
```

Because `$1` gets expanded to `*.txt`, which gets expanded to, say `foo.txt bar.txt`, which gets passed to `test -f`.

Short of explicitly checking for wildcard characters, is there a general way to perform a shell substitution, and then prevent any globbing?

Comment: OIC, basically a duplicate of this StackOverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10452107/prevent-globbing-after-variable-substitution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, globs are **not** expanded when quoted, so:

```
set -- '*.txt'
[ -f "$1" ]
```

Will check whether the file called `*.txt` in the current directory is a regular file or a symlink to a regular file.

```
[ -f $1 ]
```

would be a problem (`$1` would undergo word splitting (here not doing anything with the default value of `$IFS`) and filename generation).

If you wanted to check whether there were regular files with a `.txt` extension, you'd need a loop or use `find` or `zsh` glob qualifiers.

```
set -- *.txt
for f do
  if [ -f "$f" ]; then
    echo "there is at least one regular file with a .txt extension here"
  fi
done
```

Or if the pattern is found in `$1`:

```
IFS= # disable the splitting part of the split+glob operator
set -- $1
for f do... # as above
```

`zsh`:

```
files=(*.txt(N-.))
echo "$#files regular files with a .txt extension here"
```

`find`:

```
find -L . ! -name . -prune ! -name '.*' -name '*.txt' -type f | grep -q . &&
  echo there are regular .txt files in here
```

Comment: Thanks, I do need to use the $1 though. Perhaps I should have explained the task: a script that does when thing when passed a single filename (displays it), and another thing when passed a directory or file mask (runs `ls`). The "*.txt" is just one example of something that might be passed to the script.

Comment: @SteveBennett, if your script is called as `my-script *.txt`, then the calling shell will expand that `*.txt` before calling the script. `my-script` will receive `bar.txt` in `$1` and `foo.txt` in `$2`... You shouldn't need to expand wildcards in your script.

Comment: Oh...yes, you're right. Ok, so if my script receives two arguments, it was given a wildcard. No way to distinguish between `my-script foo.txt` and `my-script *.txt` if there is only one txt file?

Comment: No way no. Just as there's no way to tell if the script was called as `my-script $files` or `my-script "${files[@]}"` or `my-script $(ls)`.

Comment: Having said that, `bash-2.0` (and `bash-2.0` only) used to pass an environment variable (`_<pid>_GNU_nonoption_argv_flags_` which specified which of the arguments were the result of globbing (and that was used by `getopt` to know which arguments it shouldn't consider as options). That was removed quickly after though as causing too much trouble.

Comment: Ok, so in the end the best workaround is checking for $2. Thanks.

Comment: @SteveBennett, check for `$#` (the number of arguments)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Very interesting bit of historical trivia about bash 2.0!

Comment: `IFS= # disable the globbing part of the split+glob operator` -- I think it does quite the opposite: disable the splitting part, but not the glob.